# How to wire this into MOLEX

Tags: dc, monitor

I've taken apart old LCD monitor and i would like to power the LCD panel from molex connector, on which i will cut one plastic connector and use the wires. Since molex has 5V gnd gnd and 12V it's perfect for my use as i need to power the LCD screen board and LED strip. Originally the monitor was powered from outlet 220V through switching adapter to barrel jack, photos attached. I would like to clip the barrel jack and connect the wires directly to molex on my PC, but I'm unsure about the wires. I've stripped some part of wire and the connector itself and found this. Three black thick wires are connected to outer shell and three thin red black brown wires are going into the middle of the connector. I assume the thick ones are ground but what are the three thin ones? An, advice how could i wire that? Thanks a ton! [image][image] [image]

Comment: Do you still have the original power brick?  If so, try disconnecting the black rectangular header and measuring voltages when the other end is connected to the brick.

Comment: But you don't even know if the barrel input is 5v or 12v or something else?

Comment: Yup i do have the original, but I don't have anything to measure with. The input should be 12V since the power brick says output is 12V 3A right?